# PHP Fancybox same ID

Tags: php, fancybox

This may seem like a weird request, but this is something I have to use based on something I have been provided that is live.

I have a voting system that uses an id for the voting button based on the entry id, so the code looks like:

```
<div class="like_wrap">
    <div class="vot_plus" id="vt_img41"></div>
</div><!--like_wrap-->
```

This works how I need it to, however when you click the image within the vote it opens up a larger picture of the entry (again this works), but the client would like to add that vote to the fancybox popup.  However when this is added it removes all references as it is calling the same ID twice.  Any idea how I can get the voting button to appear on both, but actually look like it only appears once?

Here is the full code of an entry:

```
<div class="single ">
    <a href='#inline41' rel='example_group' title='NAME GOES HERE'><img src='IMAGE GOES HERE' height='90' width='90' class='image' /></a>
    <div class="right_col">
        <h3>NAME GOES HERE</h3>
        <div class="like_wrap"><div class="vot_plus" id="vt_img41"></div></div><!--like_wrap-->
    </div><!--right_col-->

    <div class="clear"></div><!--clear-->

    <div id="inline41" style="display: none;">
        <img src='IMAGE GOES HERE' height='400' class='image' /></a>
        <div class="vote_bottom">
            <p>Vote: </p>
            <div class="like_wrap"><div class="vot_plus" id="vt_img41"></div></div><!--like_wrap-->
            <div class="clear"></div><!--clear-->
        </div><!--vote_bottom-->
    </div>
</div><!--single-->
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use same ID? ID = Unique identifier. Notice *Unique*?

Comment: This was code I had inherited and as this is currently live if I make changes to take off the ID it could be problematic! So I was wondering whether there was a way around this?

Comment: Is voting button disappearing inside fancybox?

Comment: I should have said that earlier, but yes it is disappearing off main screen and only appearing on fancybox! Any ideas?